# Confused by middleware execution process, DJANGO

Tags: python, django, middleware

Suppose I have the following class, as inspired by the Django documentation:

> ```
> class SimpleMiddleware(object):
>
>     def __ init__(self, get_response):
>         self.get_response = get_response
>
>     def __call__(self, request):
>
>
>         response = self.get_response(request)
>
>   
>         return response
>
>     def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
>
>         return None
> ```

When reading Daniel Rubio's book 'Beginning Django', he explains that the order of execution is:

1. `__ init __` method triggered (on server startup)
2. `__ call __` method triggered (on every request)
3. If declared, `process_view()` method triggered
4. View method starts with `self.get_response(request)` statement in `__ call __`

What exactly does "`__ call __` method triggered (on every request)" mean? Does not 'triggering' the `__ call __` method actually trigger '`self.get_respone(request)`' automatically, thus calling either another middleware or a class?

The Django documentation states that:

> `process_view()` is called just before Django calls the view.`

To me, this would have to mean that Django checks if the instance of the `'SimpleMiddleware'` class contains a method `'process_view()'` and then triggers that, before moving on to calling the `__ call __()` method, which 'calls the view'? Otherwise, if the `__ call __` method is triggered immediately, won't '`process_view()`' be missed since the `__ call __` method calls the view (or the next middleware)?

Could someone please help me understand the execution process? How does Django go about this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you read [the middleware documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/)? It's pretty well explained there.

Comment: Yes, and it was indeed a good resource. Can I assume that their statement 'process_view() is called just before Django calls the view' means that the process_view' method is run before '__ call __ '?

Answer (score 10):

You are mixing up [old style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) (pre django 1.10) and [new style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) middlewares. The new style looks as follows:

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # do stuff with request
        response = self.get_response(request)
        # do stuff with request and/or response
        return response
```

The old style equivalent of that was:

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        # do stuff with request
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # do stuff with request and/or response
```

In order to make it easier to port old code to the new way of doing things, django has added the [MiddlewareMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin) ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/deprecation.py#L82)):

```
class MiddlewareMixin:
    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        self.get_response = get_response
        super().__init__()

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = None
        if hasattr(self, 'process_request'):
            response = self.process_request(request)
        response = response or self.get_response(request)
        if hasattr(self, 'process_response'):
            response = self.process_response(request, response)
        return response
```

All you have to do now with your old style middlewares is to make them subclass this mixin. But generally, new style middlewares do not per se have or need the `process_...` methods. But e.g.:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class SimpleMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        # do stuff with request
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # do stuff with request and/or response
```

will work in both worlds.

Comment: But process_view() is, among some other hooks, included in the new style middleware? At least it seems so from the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/